# Can someone tell me why my file sorter dont work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sorting, shutil

This is my code in python for my file sorter and i dont know why it dont work

```py
import os
import shutil

path = str(input("Enter the path you want to sort: "))

def moveFile(path):
    path1 = path
    path = os.listdir(path)
    for file in path:
        if file.endswith(".gif") or file.endswith(".jfif") or file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg") or file.endswith(".png"):
            shutil.move(f"{path1}\\{file}", "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Pictures\\Pictures\\")
            break
        elif file.endswith(".mp4") or file.endswith(".mkv") or file.endswith(".avi"):
            shutil.move(f"{path1}\\{file}", "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Videos\\Videos\\")
            break
        elif file.endswith(".mp3") or file.endswith(".wav") or file.endswith(".m4a"):
            shutil.move(f"{path1}\\{file}", "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Music\\Songs\\")
            break
        elif file.endswith(".exe"):
            shutil.move(f"{path1}\\{file}", "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\App\\")
            break
        elif file.endswith(".txt") or file.endswith(".docx") or file.endswith(".pptx") or file.endswith(".pdf"):
            shutil.move(f"{path1}\\{file}", "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Work\\")
            break
        elif file.endswith(".py") or file.endswith(".c") or file.endswith(".cpp") or file.endswith(".java") or file.endswith(".js") or  file.endswith(".html") or file.endswith(".css"):
            shutil.move(f"{path1}\\{file}", "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Code\\")
            break
        else:
            shutil.move(file, "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Other\\")
            break
        print(f"Moved:\t{file}\t")

moveFile(path)
```

Here is my error

```
Enter the path you want to sort: C:\Document
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tools\python\Portable_Python-3.9.9 x64\App\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 815, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable: 'chrome_100_percent.pak' -> 'C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Other\\chrome_100_percent.pak'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\PycharmProjects\file-filter\sorter.py", line 33, in <module>
    moveFile(path)
  File "C:\Users\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\PycharmProjects\file-filter\sorter.py", line 29, in moveFile
    shutil.move(file, "C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE\\Other\\")
  File "C:\Tools\python\Portable_Python-3.9.9 x64\App\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 835, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Tools\python\Portable_Python-3.9.9 x64\App\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 444, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Tools\python\Portable_Python-3.9.9 x64\App\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chrome_100_percent.pak'
```

This is the entire error message. I dont know why it dont works but i did it with a folder with 1 picture inside of it and my program worked. But when y tried with a folder with different type of file inside of it it dont work.
Can someone help me please ?

(ps: some text are in french sorry)

Comment: 'for file in path' is almost certainly not what you want.  That's just iterates over the string, letter by letter.  You probably want 'for file in os.listdir(path)'.  You could debug this by printing out 'file' as you loop over and you'd see what you did ;)

Comment: @Max thank you, I change it but now there is another error

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @Bharel why cant it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear how the code shown can result in that error.

This kind of code should be "table driven" which results in less code and more extensibility.

Something like this:

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join, isfile
from shutil import move
from pathlib import Path

BASE = 'C:\\Users\\CLEMENT.LAPORTE'
DEFAULT = 'Other'

CONTROL = {('gif', 'jfif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'): 'Pictures\\Pictures',
           ('mp4', 'mkv', 'avi'): 'Videos\\Videos',
           ('mp3', 'wav', 'm4a'): 'Music\\Songs',
           ('exe',): 'App',
           ('txt', 'docx', 'pptx', 'pdf'): 'Work',
           ('py', 'c', 'cpp', 'java', 'js', 'html', 'css'): 'Code'}


def moveFiles(path):
    for file in glob(join(path, '*.*'):
        suffix = Path(file).suffix[1:]
        for k, v in CONTROL.items():
            if suffix in k:
                p = v
                break
        else:
            p = DEFAULT
        try:
            move(file, join(BASE, p))
            print(f"Moved: {file} -> {p}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Failed to move {file} -> {p} due to {e}')


path = input("Enter the path you want to sort: ")

moveFiles(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `\\` in the paths with `/` and it should normally work, if not, the specified files do not exist (try to either change them or add a condition that create a folder if t doesn't find it)